# Set android window title bar icon from custom application theme

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to set the window title bar title and icon from my own custom theme?
when i create a new Android project in eclipse and have it use AppTheme as shown here

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
```

the window title bar title and icon appear as i want them.

When i select my own theme in the mainfest file only the title shows in the window title bar and not the icon.

My theme is as follows

```
style name="GenericWallpaper" parent="android:Theme.Light"
item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/blackbackground
item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent
item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent
```

I would rather use my xml style file to specify the icon and title are required than having to set it programatically in the window title bar in every activity.

I am using `android:minSdkVersion="8"`, `android:targetSdkVersion="15"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Action Bar Style Generator](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/05/android-action-bar-style-generator.html). It is a free and open source tool made by Jeff Gilfelt.

You can also have a look on a more complete blog post about Styling the ActionBar : [Part 1](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1240) and [Part 2](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1249)